# Path must be a string. Received [ 'src/index.html' ]

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to get [grunt-responive-images-extender](https://github.com/stephanmax/grunt-responsive-images-extender) to work, but keep getting this Warning.

```
Warning: Path must be a string. Received [ 'src/index.html' ] Use --force to continue.
```

My gruntfile task looks like this

```
    responsive_images_extender:{
        target: {
            options: {},
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: ['index.{html,htm,php}'],
                cwd: 'src',
                dest: 'dist/'
            }]
        }
    }
```

Why is the warning is generated? Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try adding a forward slash to the current working directory --> cwd: 'src/',

Comment: Apparently this warning is an issue caused by the node >v6, the plugin gives the path as a string inside an array, which works fine with node <v6, but from v6 and above node requires a string (not in an array). There has been an [issue](https://github.com/stephanmax/grunt-responsive-images-extender/issues/12) posted on the github page